# App is not visible in google play store for samsung galaxy note sgh i717

Tags: android, android-manifest, google-play

recently I have uploaded an app in play strore, it is not visible when searched from client's device Samsung Galaxy Note SGH I717(Located in US). When tried it from the system using browser, it says that it is not compatible as it has 'No Carrier', as there is no sim card inserted in the device.

But when we tested it from our end in India, on a different device without sim it showed up.
Even the client's device model is among the 'Supported devices list' provided by the google.

Here is my manifest, please check if any manifest declaration is causing it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="abc.abc.abc"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="13"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <compatible-screens>

        <screen
            android:screenDensity="hdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="normal" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
            android:screenDensity="480"
            android:screenSize="large" />
        <screen
            android:screenDensity="213"
            android:screenSize="large" />
    </compatible-screens>

       <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:largestWidthLimitDp="600"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="360" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <!-- Keeps the processor from sleeping when a message is received. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />
    <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="abc.abc.abc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="abc.abc.abc.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<!-- This is required for google maps -->
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.telephony"
        android:required="false" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="abc.abc.abc.Activity1"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="abc.abc.abc.Activity2"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey finally I could find a solution. Took out the support-screens tag from the manifest and it is now available to download in the Samsung galaxy sgh I717 device from play store.